# Messed Up Video for Quake2

Tags: video, configuration

I was trying to find the optimal video settings for Quake2 on my Ubuntu 20.04 laptop and messed up the video, so that I cannot change the video settings on the native screen.

Does anyone know where this config file would be for Quake2's video setting?

I tried uninstalling the quake2 package, even using -purge, and the same with game-data-packager as well, and then reinstalled.